# Rebooting caused theme to look like Windows 95 or Gnome Classic

Tags: unity, themes

My PC has recently received a *fresh* Ubuntu 13.04 install. There is nothing else on the PC apart from a very basic setup of 13.04.

After rebooting, I noticed so many problems with the way Ubuntu looked:

- Mouse pointer very large, blurry
- Applications don't have a global menu bar
- Font is all weird... is it open sans instead of Ubuntu?
- Right click context menu has little coloured icons in it
- Most applications look like Windows 95

I've tried:

- unity-revamp
- unity --reset
- changing the theme from Ambiance and back again
- creating new user account (looks ok in other account, but switching back is the same)
- removing custom themes directories (there were none at ~/.theme, ~/themes)
- Installing proprietary drivers (this made everything much faster and smoother, but didn't fix the weird theme)

Here's some screenshots of what things look like now:

[image]

[image]

Can someone help my Ubuntu get back to its beautiful self?

Comment: Did you install anything before rebooting ?

Comment: Yeah, just the usual: google chrome, sublime text, gimp, inkscape, openshot, audacity, xchat, mysql, php5, lighttpd

Comment: This is an error whth your graphics driver. To get the beautifull theme work again download your graphic card driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A colleague fixed this for me:

We basically went through all hidden directories within the home directory and moved them to a backup folder...

It was after removing `~/.gconf` I noticed that everything, **slowly**, started fixing itself.

Once booted, I first noticed the font was back to the normal Ubuntu font, and then in front of my very eyes the global menu bar popped up to the top-bar, and then the colours popped magically back to life.

The last thing to fix itself, was the mouse pointer, which reduced in size **as I was typing this answer**.

As much as this fixed my problem, I *really* don't have a clue why this occurred, or what file within gconf was the culprit...

Comment: I'm keeping this answer open for now, as after returning from my lunch I have **a big fat mouse pointer** again ... let's see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

Removing `~/.gconf` didn't fix it for me. I found that my particular case was probably due to [a crash of `upowerd`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/1305699).

What I did to fix it:

- `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils`
- Unplug all USB devices (for me it was a headset, Windows Phone, and iPod)
- Reboot